# python beginner: import mysite.manage fails?

Tags: python, django, pyinstaller

Disclaimer: I am new to python and django but have Drupal programming experience. I'm using Windows 7 (same issues on Windows XP)

On python 2.7 and Django-1.3.1, I successfully created a default project

```
django-admin.py startproject djsite
```

Now, I need to "bootstrap" djsite.manage as explained here (http://www.pyinstaller.org/wiki/Recipe/DjangoApplication) in a file called bootstrap.py located in djsite's parent directory as follows:

```
import djsite.manage
djsite.manage.execute_manager(djsite.manage.settings,['manage.py', 'runserver'])
```

Yet, as soon as the compiler sees:

```
import djsite.manage
```

I get this:
"Error: Can't find the file 'settings.py' in the directory containing 'C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\djsite\manage.pyc'. It appears you've customized things... You'll have to run django-admin.py, passing it your settings module." And, I don't know how to follow the error's advice in this situation.

However, if I instead issue the following in bootstrap.py:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('djsite'))
import djsite.manage
djsite.manage.execute_manager(djsite.manage.settings,['manage.py', 'runserver'])
```

the script works correctly, but it breaks Pyinstaller (I've already asked this question on that software's mailing list (http://groups.google.com/group/pyinstaller/browse_thread/thread/174a72e26c26a44c). Even if I add the path to the djsite in my PATH variable, I get the same error.

So my question here is this: Why does importing the manage.py module fail with this approach and how can I proceed? Thanks!

Comment: From where do you execute the django-admin command ? And please dump your entire arbo and a link to your settings.py in a pastebin.

Comment: django-admin: C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\bin
settings.py: http://pastebin.com/QSNM0uie
arbo: what is an arbo?

Comment: File arborescence. And for the django-admin command, I mean "what directory are you in when you run it".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your bootstrap.py to inform it where your settings file lives:

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'djsite.settings'
```

This will assume that djsite is in your pythonpath. That is, if its located here: `/path/to/my/djsite`, then this should be in your pythonpath: `/path/to/my`

Actually the best way to be doing this from the start is to being using [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) which will ensure that your environment is correct. I feel like that had to have been part of your tutorial if I remember bootstrap at all. If you are using virtualenv, make sure you remembered to `source bin/activate`

If that doesn't work, you can try altering the runserver command:

```
args = ['manage.py', 'runserver', '--settings=/path/to/my/djsite/settings.py']
djsite.manage.execute_manager(djsite.manage.settings, args)
```

Comment: thanks jdi. I tried all 3 suggestions (took about 2 hours to learn virtualenv -- cool project) but no luck. results follow: 

1. import os... Error: Can't find the file 'settings.py' in the directory containing 'C:\\python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\djsite\\manage.pyc'. It appears you've customized things...

2. same error in the virtual environment, and in windows the source bin/activate is issued through activate.bat

3. args = ...: Error: Can't find the file 'settings.py' in the directory containing 'C:\\python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\djsite\\manage.pyc'. It appears you've customized things...

Comment: How did you go about creating your project to start? For some reason it looks like you made it in the python site packages location

Comment: Also if you didnt do this already, you should first creat and activate your virtualenv. Then you can use pip or whatever to install django. This will put it in tour virtualenv lib. Then create your project. I dont see why it wouldnt work after that.